# SQL Server 2008 Finding the user

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have question about the sql query.

I am trying to make the query that user who has all gun type times. For example.

I have table

**ITEM.**

```
|itemid |item_name|
| 1     | GunBow  |
| 2     | GunLong |
| 3     | GunShot |
|4      | SwordSm |
|5      | SwordLg |
|6      | Cannon  |
```

and I have table

**userinventory**

```
|used_id | name_item |
|1       | GunBow    |
|1       | GunLong   |
|1       | GunShot   |
| 2      | GunBow    |
|2       | SwardLg   |
| 2      | Cannon    |
| 3      | GunBow    |
|  3     | GunShot   |
```

Since user "1" has all of guns, I would like make query that returning the user 1.

What I did was...

```
Create Table #tmp(
Classname [varchar](50) NOT NULL
)

INSERT INTO #tmp SELECT DISTINCT iteam_name  
FROM ITEM WHERE item_name  like 'Gun%'
```

then.... I would like to compare to find user who has all of item..

However, I am not really sure how to do it.. because I can not use count or any aggression

Does anyway know they way to find user id who has all of Gun?

Comment: Why doesn't item have some kind of type designator, instead of embedding type information into the name?

Comment: I am not really sure how to do it..and it requires to do this way :(

Comment: userid=1 has only three guns as per your item table. How did you say that he has all the guns.. ?

Comment: yes, i want to build query which only get user id = 1 because user 1 is only user who has all of gun.

Comment: No, userId = 1 is missing 3 weapons (EG: Cannon)

Comment: @MostyMostacho He needs only those three guns..

Comment: @Dc Redwing  You can check the solution.I have done this problem on SQLFiddle too.

Comment: I'm not saying anything really constructive here, but If I am understanding redwing's question right it's a curiosity in that it's an example of "[relational division](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/divided-we-stand-the-sql-of-relational-division/)", I don't know that I've ever seen any questions come up like this in the so-called "real" world; I've never needed it myself.  And Venk's count-comparing method resembles Celko's central "gimmick" in the article linked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT Q.user_id
FROM
(
  SELECT DISTINCT item_name FROM item WHERE item_name LIKE 'Gun%'
) P,

(
 SELECT DISTINCT X.name_item,Y.user_id
 FROM userinventory X, 
  (SELECT user_id,COUNT(DISTINCT name_item) as count_guns_userid
  FROM userinventory
  WHERE name_item LIKE 'Gun%'
  GROUP BY user_id
 )Y
WHERE X.user_id=Y.user_id  
) Q
WHERE P.item_name=Q.name_item
GROUP BY Q.user_id
HAVING COUNT(Q.name_item)=3;
```

Check the solution here on SQL Fiddle - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d10b2/1

Comment: This will not work. I had thought to put that, but it has a flaw (unless the schema enforces against it). What if a user has 2 of the same type of gun (this can be seen by changing your SQLFiddle to have two GunBow and a GunShot (no GunLong) for user 1). Then the counts will still match. However, in typing this up, I thought about it a little more, you could do a COUNT(DISTINCT item_name) and it should work.